# Pandas: groupby followed by aggregate - unexpected behaviour when joining strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

Having a `pandas` data frame containing two columns of type `str`:

```
    group   sc  wc
0   1       A   word1
1   2       B   word2
2   2       C   word3
3   1       D   word4
```

which is created as follows:

`df = pd.DataFrame({"group":[1,2,2,1],"sc":["A","B","C","D"],"wc":["word1", "word2", "word3","word4"]})`

When grouping by `group` and joining the individual columns, I can use:

```
df.groupby("group",as_index=False).agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x))

    group   sc  wc
0   1   A|D word1|word4
1   2   B|C word2|word3
```

However, when specifying a single column (`wc`) to perform this operation on:

```
df.groupby("group",as_index=False)["wc"].agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x))

    group   wc
0   1   group|sc|wc
1   2   group|sc|wc
```

which appears to be a `join` on the column names. **But why is it handled this way?**

A proper implementation would make use of `apply`:

```
df.groupby("group",as_index=False)["wc"].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x))

    group   wc
0   1   word1|word4
1   2   word2|word3
```

I stumbled upon this, as I wanted to avoid apply for larger dataframes to due performance issues (in my case it is 4-fold increase of speed using `agg` over `apply`).

What actually want to do is a `join` each value of `sc` and `wc` and then combine the groups into a single string like:

```
df["merged"] = df.sc + "|" + df.wc
df.groupby("group",as_index=False).agg('|'.join))

    group   sc  wc  merged
0   1   A|D word1|word4 A|word1|D|word4
1   2   B|C word2|word3 B|word2|C|word3
```

There is even more to it, once integers are used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"group":[1,2,2,1],"sc":[3,33,333,3333],"wc":[1,10,100,1000]})
df["merged"] = df.sc.astype(str) + "|" + df.wc.astype(str)
df.groupby(["group"],as_index=False).agg('|'.join)

    group   merged
0   1   3|1|3333|1000
1   2   33|10|333|100
```

This indicates that `join` is only run on the string columns.

The consecutive `join` and `agg` saves me a lot of computational time but does not feel right. Any insights are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug related to `GroupBy.agg` that manifests because of `as_index=False` - the entire subgroup DataFrame is passed to `agg`. Remove that and the output is as expected.

```
df.groupby("group")["wc"].agg('|'.join).reset_index()
 
   group           wc
0      1  word1|word4
1      2  word2|word3
```

When the subgroup is passed with its columns, calling `str.join` will join the column names, like so

```
'|'.join(df)
# 'group|sc|wc'  # this joins on the column names because iteration 
                 # on dataFrames devolves to iteration over headers
```

Do note that there is little difference between using `agg` and `apply` with a function that is non-cythonized (or at the very least, does not have fastpaths).